# High DPI powershell form

Tags: .net, forms, powershell, dpi

I have a form create to give information about the computer you are on and when we deployed it to surface pro 4's we didnt think about the DPI and it explodes the test and is unreadable in the form. See below.

BAD form:

[image: Bad form]

This is how it should look:

[image: Good-Form]

I have tried all the AutoSizeMode and putting it into groups and tables and nothing seems to work. Im putting it up on StackOverflow to see if anyone has a good solution. Here is my base to the form:

```
#Background Image
$Image = [system.drawing.image]::FromFile("Desktop.jpg")

$Form.BackgroundImage = $Image

$Form.BackgroundImageLayout = "Stretch"


#button
$Button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button 
$Button.TabIndex = 0 
$Button.Name = "Button" 
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size 
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 160
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 30 
$Button.Size = $System_Drawing_Size 
$Button.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True

$Button.Text = "Button"
$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point 
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 13
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 230
$Button.Location = $System_Drawing_Point 
$Button.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0 
$Button.add_Click({Function1})


$Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Calibri",11.5 [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Regular)
$Form.Font = $Font


#Lables for the computer information and displays them
$Label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$Label.Text = "`n Phone: $CallServiceDesk `n E-Mail: `n IP Address: $IPAddress `n Computer Name: $env:computername `n Username: $env:username `n     Domain: $env:userdomain `n HomeServer: $env:HOMESERVER `n AssetTag: $env:TIA `n Service Tag: $env:servicetagsn `n McAfee Proxy: $Proxy"
$Label.BackColor = "Transparent"
$Label.AutoSize = $True

$Form.Controls.Add($Email_Label)
$Form.Controls.Add($Call_Label)
$Form.Controls.Add($Label)
$Form.Controls.Add($Button)
$Form.Controls.Add($Learn_Label)


$Form.ShowDialog() 

if ($Form -eq "Cancel"){exit}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by adding `[System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit]::Pixel` in my font variable

```
$Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI",13,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Regular,[System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit]::Pixel)
$Form.Font = $Font
```